# Angular router events subscribe event type "any"

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router

I am using the following code to find out the URL at the NavigationEnd event of the router.

```
        this.router.events
            .pipe(filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
            .subscribe((ev: any) => {
                let url = ev.url;})
```

I don't want to use "any" in the code. What should I replace it with? I tried "NavigationEnd" and "Event" instead of "Any". In both cases, I got the "No overload matches this call." error.

Comment: With my opinion , your error message have a bit strange, can you edit your post by giving full code that included import section?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **type predicate** on the `filter` fn to help Typescript decipher what's the filter intention like this.

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((ev: NavigationEnd) => {
    let url = ev.url;
  });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Event from @angular/router i think.. you can import it

Comment: But on your subscribe the event type is NavigationEnd, because you are filtered only for that

Comment: I tried NavigaionEnd. But I am getting following error.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Event_2>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(ev: NavigationEnd) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Event_2>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Event_2>>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
.subscribe((e: NavigationEnd) => {
        let url = e.url;       
 });
```

Comment: I tried that. Its giving an error. No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Event_2>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(ev: NavigationEnd) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Event_2>>'.

Answer (score 0):

`RouterEvent` must be what you need.

```
  this.router.events
    .pipe(filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe((ev: RouterEvent) => {
      console.log(ev.url);
  });
```

Comment: I tried it. It's still giving an errror.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Event_2>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(ev: NavigationEnd) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Event_2>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Event_2

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a RxJS [observer](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observer) object to the `subscribe()` function instead of individual callback.

```js
import { NavigationEnd, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e: RouterEvent) => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe({
  next: (e: NavigationEnd) => {
    let url = ev.url;
  }
});
```